# Hello, I have been working on android project where I need to send the selected String from listview to another activity

Tags: android, listview

In my program I have fetched the data's from the server and view it in a listview. Then from those retrieved data in listview I have to select a string and that string will be passed on to another activity. My data's are retrieved and showed in listview but when I select an item(String) and try to send it to the next activity then instead of that string the package name is passed. 
The layout code for retrieving and sending selected String is given below:

```
    public class Doctors_layout extends Fragment implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    public final static String Message = "Sohan";
    View myView;
    Spinner spinner;
    String selectedCity;
    Context myContext;
    String jsonResult;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    String JSON_String;
    ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    Button button;
    String send;
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doctors_directory, container, false);
        myContext = inflater.getContext();
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(myContext, R.layout.row_layout);
        spinner = (Spinner)myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        listView = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        List<String> city = new ArrayList<String>();
        city.add("Choose a City");
        city.add("Chittagong");
        city.add("Dhaka");
        ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,city);
        aAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(aAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // here we have to select medical name and intent viewDoctor page
                Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, viewDoctor.class);
                send = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();      // doesn't retrieve the selected text, intead chooses package name
                intent.putExtra(Message, send);
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Listview item "+send, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return myView;
    }
```

And my custom contact adapter class is given below:

```
package com.example.sohan.patient;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Sohan on 6/9/2016.
 */
public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    View row;
    ContactHolder contactHolder;
    public ContactAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }


    public void add(List<Contacts> updatedList) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(updatedList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        row = convertView;

        if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            contactHolder = new ContactHolder();
            contactHolder.MedicalName =(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            row.setTag(contactHolder);
        }
        else{

            contactHolder = (ContactHolder)row.getTag();
        }



        Contacts contacts = (Contacts)this.getItem(position);
        contactHolder.MedicalName.setText(contacts.getMedicalName());
        return row;



    }

    static class ContactHolder{
        TextView MedicalName;
    }

}
```

Comment: You dont need to take string from listview row but from an array that you are passing to listview. so array.get(position).getMedicalName() for example would be how you retrieve medical name for certain position in lsitview

Comment: Thnx a lott, it worked.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
send = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

you are sending a listView object and not actual string.

use:

send = yourListOfStrings.get(position)

UDP:

You are trying to create an adapter with onItemClick listener attacked to it:

```
contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(myContext, R.layout.row_layout);
spinner = (Spinner)myView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
listView = (ListView)myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

right?
So you are suppose to fill(But I haven't found where you are doing this) this adapter with some data:

```
 public void add(List<Contacts> updatedList) {
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(updatedList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

and you want to send a string from from the element of this list to another acitvity, right?

So you need to select an element of this list

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    send = updatedList.get(position).getYourString
```

inside onItemClickListener

Comment: Didn't understand, Can you be more specific please.. what is yourListOfSTring??

Comment: also, condier to look for examples in the internet. I assume that you copied this code from somewhere and haven't carefully read it.

Comment: Thnx for your explanations, I didn't copy the code, I saw some tutorials and then applied these concepts to my project..

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it work...

```
send = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5)).getText().toString();
```

or

```
send = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

thanks..

Comment: Nope, app crashed.